# Pre process a template that uses layout display

Tags: 8, layout-builder

I want to preprocess a user account display. I want to manipulate a field value at display time.
for example, i want to change:
**field_prefered_color:** red
to :
**field_prefered_color:** red - Cool, that is used 5 times today.

If I don't use layout builder I can easily change that in

```
function mymodule_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['field_prefered_color'][0]['#context'][['value'] .= t(' - Cool, that is used @times times today,['@times' => $times]);
}
```

But when I use layout builder, where can I find field_prefered_color to manipulate its output?

Comment: Can you just use the hook_preprocess_field method? Layout will be calling this when it inserts the field.

Comment: Yes I can, however... I need the user id of the user being viewed. That is not provided in the variables in hook_preprocess_field. That's why I need to be in hook_preprocess_user. I might be able to drill down from $variables['_layout_builder'] but if you change from one to two columns the structure of the array _layout_builder changes as well. It looks like it is extremely hard to override the fields that are in a layout.

Answer (score 0):

It appears quite easy to achieve what I want:
I needed to create a conditional field functionality. I know there is a module for that but at this time the module is not stable and not performing well with layout builder.
As indicated by @CG Monroe the last called template is field.html.twig.
If this is a user field the fully loaded user is available in:

```
$variables['elements']['#object']
```

So I could access all the user fields I needed to manipulate the field output in the preprocess function

```
function my_module_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $field = $variables['elements']['#object']->field_some_other_field->value;
  // now I can manipulate the output of the field being viewed
  // the manipulation is needed because of the value of "some-other-field"
  $variables['items'][0]['content']['#context']['value'] = ' ***  ****';
  $variables['items'][0]['attributes']->addClass('my-module-field-manipulated');
}
```